# android camera flash light turns off on changing orientation

Tags: android, flash, camera, onconfigurationchanged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash light is getting switch off while changing the orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637377/flash-light-is-getting-switch-off-while-changing-the-orientation)

I am building an android app. On configuration change the flash light goes off. Then I need to again click the ON button to make it on.  how can it remain switched on in my app?

Comment: You know anything about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7899767/940096)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic problem is that configuration change by default recreates Activity, so if you do some recurse management in activity you have to remember that.

There are two opposite solutions:

1. disable recreation of Activity on configuration change by adding in manifest property [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) of Activity list of configuration changes which you will handle manually, for example `"keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` (`screenSize` is needed since Adnroid 3.1). In this case you can handle configuration change by overriding method [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29).
2. handle recreation of activity by overriding method [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and saving state of activity there inside of bundle. Then in `onCreate` when parameter `savedInstanceState` is set (not null) you should restore state from that bundle (restore state of flash light).

Choice of method depends of you activity design.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to your activity in android manifest file.

Comment: I have done that. I will send you my code:

Comment: on button click :
if (isLighOn) {
 
     Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");
 
     p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
     camera.setParameters(p);
     camera.stopPreview();
     isLighOn = false;
 
    } else {
 
     Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");
 
     p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
 
     camera.setParameters(p);
     camera.startPreview();
     isLighOn = true;
 
    }

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are changing the orientation the full activity is been destroyed and a new activity is been created.So what happening is that the activity is loosing the current state of the flash and it turns off.

Try disabling the orientation changes in the manifest.And save the current state of the flsh in the Onstop and reset the state in the OnStart.

This will work for you I believe.

Comment: not working for me can i mail you my code?